# Fitting arcs on a contour using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a project in OpenCV where I have a contour and I have to fit some arcs with defined arc length, radius, chord length, and angle. With fit, I mean I have to choose the best arc, that would cover a piece of the contour.

What I have tried till now is in all the contours, I have found corners which are acting as my segments, then using some linear algebra I am calculating the radius and the center of the circle that would best fit that segment and then comparing this with all the other arcs, radius and central angle and fitting the with the least difference in values. This approach is not helping me much as the arcs that I am getting don't lie on the contour. Code is attached

```
for contours in final_contours:
  iter = 0
  dict_sorted, sorted_corners = sortCorners(contours, corners)
  keys_dict_sorted = sorted(dict_sorted.keys())

  for key in keys_dict_sorted:
    [x, y] = dict_sorted[key] 
    bl_img = cv2.circle(bl_img, (x, y), 3, (255, 0, 0), -1)
  
  # cv2_imshow(bl_img)
  for i in range(len(keys_dict_sorted) ):
    if (i != len(keys_dict_sorted)-1):
      idx1 = keys_dict_sorted[i]
      idx3 = keys_dict_sorted[i+1]
      idx2 = math.floor((keys_dict_sorted[i] + keys_dict_sorted[i+1]) / 2) 
    else:
      idx1 = keys_dict_sorted[i]
      idx3 = keys_dict_sorted[0]
      idx2 = math.floor((keys_dict_sorted[i] + keys_dict_sorted[0]) / 2)
    radius, [c_x, c_y] = betterCircleFinder(contours[idx1][0], contours[idx2][0], contours[idx3][0])
    
    if radius != -1:
      radius = round(truncate(radius, -1))
      c_x = round(truncate(c_x, -1))
      c_y = round(truncate(c_y, -1))
      pt1_angle = 180*(np.arctan2(np.array([contours[idx1][0][1]- c_y], dtype=float), np.array([contours[idx1][0][0] - c_x], dtype=float))/np.pi)
      pt2_angle = 180*(np.arctan2(np.array([contours[idx3][0][1] - c_y], dtype=float),np.array([contours[idx3][0][0] - c_x], dtype=float))/np.pi)
      # print(pt1_angle, pt2_angle)
      angle = abs(pt1_angle - pt2_angle)
      # print("Angle : ", angle)
      actualRadius = radius * inchPerPixel
      # print("Actual Radius : ", actualRadius)
      b = random.randint(0,255)
      g = random.randint(0, 255)
      r = random.randint(0,255)
      
      error = [0 for i in range(len(copings))]
      idx = 0
      for coping in copings:
        err = abs(actualRadius - (coping.radius))
        err1 = abs(angle - coping.centralAngle)
 
       

        error[idx] =  (0.5 * err/actualRadius) + (0.5 * err1[0]/coping.centralAngle)
        idx+=1
        # bl_img = draw_coris(bl_img, int(coping.radius * pixelPerInch), 0, pt1_angle, pt1_angle + coping.centralAngle , (c_x, c_y), (b, g,r), 5)
        # cv2_imshow(bl_img)
      index_min = min(range(len(error)), key=error.__getitem__)
      # pprint.pprint(error)
      # print(index_min, error[index_min])
      # print(copings[index_min].radius * pixelPerInch)
      
      bl_img = draw_coris(bl_img, int(copings[index_min].radius * pixelPerInch), 0, pt1_angle, pt1_angle + copings[index_min].centralAngle , (int(c_x), int(c_y)), (b, g,r), 5)

      if (abs(c_x) > (2 ** 31 -1) or abs(c_y) > (2**31 -1)):
        print("OVERFLOW VALUES")
        # cv2_imshow(bl_img)
        continue
```

```
def betterCircleFinder(pt1, pt2, pt3):
  
  A = np.array([[2*pt1[0], 2*pt1[1], 1], 
               [2*pt2[0], 2*pt2[1], 1], 
               [2*pt3[0], 2*pt3[1], 1] ])
  B = np.array([[-1 * (pt1[0] ** 2 + pt1[1]**2)], 
               [-1 * (pt2[0] ** 2 + pt2[1]**2)],
               [-1 * (pt3[0] ** 2 + pt3[1]**2)]])
  det = np.linalg.det(A)
  if (det == 0):
    return -1, [-1, -1]
  C = np.linalg.inv(A)@B
  C = np.squeeze(C)
  c_x = -1 * C[0]
  c_y = -1 * C[1]
  c = C[2]
  
  radius = math.sqrt(c_x ** 2  + c_y** 2 - c)
  return radius, [c_x, c_y]
```

This is the code that find the details of the circle that best fits the segment.